# Find intervals where a series converges and uniformly converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm not sure if I'm doing better. Here is the stuff.

Consider the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x) = nx \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\text{sinc}^n\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$ 
and the series
$$s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f_n(x).$$

**Point-wise convergence**

Since $\text{sinc}(\alpha) \leq 1$, then $f_n(x) \leq nx \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = g_n(x) $ and 
$$s(x) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} g_n(x) = t(x).$$

$g_n(x)$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes toward infinity.
Using ratio test, I get that:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{g_{n+1}(x)}{g_n(x)} = \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{-n}x^{n+2}}{n^{1-n}x^{1+n}} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{-n}x = 0 < 1.$$

Then I can state that the series $t(x)$ converges point-wise for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $s(x) \leq t(x)$, then also $s(x)$ converges point-wise for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Am I right?

**Uniform convergence**

I don't know where to start from...

Comment: You should use absolute values in your inequalities, otherwise it is false (especially for $x<0$ with $n$ even)

Comment: @stity ok, thanks a lot, I forgot about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $|f_n(x)|\le n |x|  \left|\frac{x}{n} \right|^n =\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}} \le \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n!}$ and use the fonction $|x|e^{|x|}$

**Edit :**

Hint for uniform convergence : can you show that $$||s(x)-s_N(x)||_\infty \ge f_N(\frac{\pi N}{2})=\frac{N^2\pi}{2}$$ ? (You just have to prove that $\forall k >N, f_k(\frac{\pi N}{2}) \ge 0$ ) What does that mean ?

Comment: upvoted, but I'm still missing something. You say that $s(x) \leq |x|e^|x|$, and then? Is this related to pointwise or uniform convergence?

Comment: @the_candyman I edited my answer

Comment: @slity thanks! Now it is clearer! what about pointwise convergence? Where my calculations right?

Comment: @the_candyman the first part of my answer is for the pointwise convergence, please remember to use $|\cdot|$